# Difficulty using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am tying to solve two differential equations with two delays numerically. The result didn't come out and it was written that “NDSolve::ndsz:...step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected”

Here's the code.

```
Manipulate[
Module[{plt1, plt2, sol, x0 = xx0, y0 = yy0}, 
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == d*y[t] + k*y[t - τ2], 
 y'[t] == μ*y[t - τ2]*(b*(x[t] + β)^2 + c) - μ*
    h*x[t] - μ*a*x[t - τ1] + μ*(f - g), 
 x[t /; t <= 0] == x0, y[t /; t <= 0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0,
  50}]; plt1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 50}, 
PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.6, 
PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 1], Thick}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}];
plt2 = StreamPlot[{d*y + 
  k*y, μ*y*(b*(x + β)^2 + c) - μ*h*x - μ*a*
   x + μ*(f - g)}, {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, FrameLabel -> {
  {Style[Row[{Style["x", Italic], "(", Style["t", Italic], ")"}], 
    14], None},
  {Style[Row[{Style["y", Italic], "(", Style["t", Italic], ")"}], 
    14], Style[Row[{Style["The phase portrait of system", Bold]}],
     14]}}, StreamPoints -> 50];
start = Graphics3D[Point3DBox[{xx0, yy0}]];
plt3 = {plt1, start};
Show[plt3, ImageSize -> {450, 400}]],
Style["Persamaan differensial :", Bold], Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\(x\)\(\\\ \)\), \(.\)]\)= \d*y[t]+k*y[t-τ2] ", Bold],
Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(y\), \(.\)]\) = \μ*y[t-τ2]*(b*(x[t]+β\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\\)+c)-μ*h*x[t]-μ*a*x[t-τ1]+μ*(f-g) ", Bold], 
Delimiter,
Style["parameters", Bold, 10],{{d, 1, "d"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{β, -2, "β"}, -100, 0, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c, -2, "c"}, -100, 0, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{μ, 0.13, "μ"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{a, 12, "a"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{g, 20, "g"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{h, 10, "h"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{f, 60, "f"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{b, 1, "b"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{k, 1, "k"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{τ1, 0, "τ1"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{τ2, 1, "τ2"}, 0, 100, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter,
Style["initial conditions", Bold,10], {{xx0, 0.4, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)"}, 0, 50, .01, ImageSize -> Small,Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{yy0, 0.4,"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(0\)]\)"}, 0, 50, .01,
ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Left, SynchronousUpdating -> False]`
```

I have tried the methods that have been posted in the web but it didn't work. Please give me answer how to deal with it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Does your DE have a singularity?  `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` can handle some forms of stiffness.  Search for StiffnessSwitching in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the question, the fundamental problem here is with `NDSolve`.  However, the numerous syntax errors in the code make it difficult to analyze this problem as presented.  So, extract `NDSolve` from the code and run it with the default parameters from `Manipulate`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == d*y[t] + k*y[t - τ2], 
    y'[t] == μ*y[t - τ2]*(b*(x[t] + β)^2 + c) - μ*h*x[t] - μ*a*x[t - τ1] + μ*(f - g), 
    x[t /; t <= 0] == x0, y[t /; t <= 0] == y0} /. {μ -> 0.13, d -> 1, k -> 1, τ1 -> 0, 
    τ2 -> 1, b -> 1, c -> -2, β -> -2, a -> 12, f -> 60, g -> 20, h -> 10, 
    x0 -> 0.4, y0 -> 0.4}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 50}]
```

It fails at `t = 5.07` with the error message given in the question.  Using `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`, as suggested by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2), often works in such cases but not here.  These nonlinear, delay differential equations may be intrinsically singular at finite `t` for the parameters chosen.  However, a slight change to the parameters, namely `τ2 -> .067`, does produce a stable result out to `t = 50`.

```
tm = ((x[t] /. sol) /. t -> "Domain")[[1, 1, 2]]
(* 50. *)
Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, tm}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x,y"}]
```

[image]

Note that the upper bound of the plot, here `50` is extracted from the `NDSolve` solution, so that `Plot` can provide a reasonable result, even if `NDSolve` terminates sooner than `t = 50`.  For instance, the identical code with the original `τ2 -> 1` yields

[image]

Comment: @Aulia, If you plot the default solution (`ListLinePlot[{x, y} /. First@sol]` is easy, if the OP changes the call to `{x, y}` instead of `{x[t], y[t]}`), the plot shows a probable singularity.  You can experiment whether this is a numerics problem or a DE problem by setting `WorkingPrecision ->16` and higher.  If the failure is at `5.07`, then it's probably a real singularity. You can write code to deal with the singularity (look up `Check` and `Quiet` for instance); a singularity is not necessarily a bad thing programatically.

Comment: I got an error I have never seen: If I set `τ2 -> .067` and also change the interval of integration to `{t, 0, Infinity}`, I get `NDSolve::ndssc: Step size changed sign at...`.  (Nothing to do with your answer, but a new error seemed fun to me.  Fixed with `MaxStepSize`.  I was doing to it to find where the solution blows up.  Just having fun.) (+1)